# cf-civicrm State/Province field dropdown not populating after country is chosen

Tags: caldera-forms

I've just started working with the cf-civicrm plugin so I may be missing something simple.

I can't get the CiviCRM State/Province select field to fill. I tested it using the "CiviCRM Contact and Address" form template after running into the issue on a form I was building. No luck. The field just returns N/A for every country I've tried.

My experience has some parallels to [this github issue](https://github.com/mecachisenros/cf-civicrm/issues/178) but the fix that worked for rbaugh isn't working for me.

Questions, tip and pointers about how to resolve this would be most welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This type of problem commonly occurs when any of these is true:

1. No default country is set
2. No default state is set
3. Available countries is not set - list on right-hand side is empty
4. Available states is not set - list on right-hand side is empty

Check your CiviCRM Localisation Settings. Below is a screenshot of a working configuration for a site in Australia that allows both Australia and USA country/state options to be selected.

[image: CiviCRM Localisation Settings]

Comment: Thanks, Justin, for your quick response. I have all of these set in my Localization Settings and the issue still persists. Any thoughts on where to look next?

Comment: As I describe in my answer below, I found that available countries and available states were the issue but default country or state had no effect, at least in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Making sure that Localisation is set is the first step.

On the form itself, you need to define a country field:

[image: Country Field]

and then the State/Province Field. In the State Field be sure you are linking to the Country Field:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Kevin, for your reply. As I describe in my answer below, I found that the CiviCRM Country field made no difference since I have only one Country/State pair in the form.

Comment: @kevin-cristiano  So I have the Country select above the State/Province select, and I have tried the CiviCRM Country slug into the CiviCRM Country field (with and without %%) but the State/Province select still shows ALL states/provinces in the list and does not limit it to the selected country. Am I missing something?

Comment: Not that I know of.   I think without % is better.  I'd see if you have localization set up.  Even if you want all countries and states/provinces try that first.

Answer (score 2):

I have it working and, at least in my case, the issue is with the handling of available countries and available states as rbaugh describes in [this github issue](https://github.com/mecachisenros/cf-civicrm/issues/177). Essentially, if you leave the right-hand box empty to include all countries (as the CiviCRM note directs), none of the states are loaded. Loading all of the countries into both right-hand boxes works.

Commenting out the foreach loop from lines 293 to 297 in [cf-civicrm/includes/class-civicrm-caldera-forms-helper.php](https://github.com/mecachisenros/cf-civicrm/blob/fe03d5312c0622bbaeeaf3c2b2d730fdea0dd7cb/includes/class-civicrm-caldera-forms-helper.php#L293) allows the fields to work in the form with the available countries right-hand box empty (with the available states empty as well).

My usage is worldwide. I need all the countries so this hack works for me but it looks like the logic around that foreach loop needs some refinement.

Along the way I did some tests.

- It works fine with no default country or state. Only the available countries and available states mattered. (See Justin Freeman's reply above.)
- Since I have only one pair of Country/State fields, the CiviCRM Country field in the State field parameter list has no effect. (See Kevin Cristiano's reply above.)

I'll report what I'm finding on the cf-civicrm github site.