# cf-civicrm State/Province field will not limit to chosen Country

Tags: wordpress, caldera-forms

So looking at this other post, I was able to get the Country select to populate with all Countries.
[cf-civicrm State/Province field dropdown not populating after country is chosen](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/37901/cf-civicrm-state-province-field-dropdown-not-populating-after-country-is-chosen)

The issue I am still having though, is the State/Province select is being populated with every single State and Province from every country in the Country select field (which is all countries), so the list is HUGE.

I can not seem to get it to limit the State/Provinces to only the selected country.

For the State/Province, I have tried putting the country slug (both %country% and just country) in the "CiviCRM Country field", and I have tried placing State/Province select both before Country select and after Country select.

Comment: Which version of the Caldera Forms CiviCRM plugin are you using?

Comment: I am using Caldera Forms plugin v1.9.7 (community maintained fork). For the processor connection, I tried CF CiviCRM by Andrei Mondoc v1.0.5 which had this issue, and then I tried switching to Caldera Forms CiviCRM by Agileware v1.0.5 which also has this same issue.

Comment: Are you getting any Javascript errors? The options are supposed to be filtered when a country is selected: https://github.com/WPCV/cf-civicrm/blob/main/fields/civicrm_state/field.php#L57

Comment: That was my initial thought, and I noticed that there was a jQuery Not Found error. I have now made sure that jQuery loads on that page, so there are no errors (javascript or otherwise) showing in the console anymore. Problem still exists.

Comment: Sorry, I'm all out of ideas. You'll have to use `error_log` and `console.log` to track the problem down, I think.

Comment: Are you needing to allow all countries or limit to one? Sounds like you need all?

Comment: @AndyBurns-iXiam All countries (well most) need to be in the country select list.